# @noinspection annotation cruft cleanup in switch statement

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have the following code which ensures that my database schema is up to date after an app update.

```
private function migrate($old_version) {

    switch ($old_version) {

        /** @noinspection PhpMissingBreakStatementInspection */
        case self::NOT_INITIALIZED:
            migrateToV0();

        /** @noinspection PhpMissingBreakStatementInspection */
        case 0:
            migrateToV1();

        /** @noinspection PhpMissingBreakStatementInspection */
        case 1:
            migrateToV2();

        /** @noinspection PhpMissingBreakStatementInspection */
        case 2:
            migrateToV3();

        case 3:
            migrateToV4();

    }
}
```

As you can see a `@noinspection` annotation must be placed before *each* `case` lest the inspector will complain that I do not have a `break` statement.

I would still like to have this warning for my code in general, so disabling that rule in general is undesirable, but it would be nice to clean it up a little. Perhaps to just one `@noinspection` before the switch statement:

```
private function migrate($old_version) {

    /** @noinspection PhpMissingBreakStatementInspection */
    switch ($old_version) {

        case self::NOT_INITIALIZED:
            migrateToV0();

        case 0:
            migrateToV1();

        case 1:
            migrateToV2();

        case 2:
            migrateToV3();

        case 3:
            migrateToV4();

    }
}
```

Is this possible in PHPStorm? Is this noinspection annotation something that comes from PHPStorm / Intellij? or is it an integrated 3rd party tool?

Answer (score 2):

In both Eclipse + CodeSniffer and PHPStorm v2016.2, all that's required is that you *show* that you are aware of the "falling-through" `switch` `case`s.

This can be as little as adding a null comment (just tested on PHPStorm v2016.2; on Eclipse, off the top of my head, a comment works, and a null comment *might*):

```
switch ($old_version) {
    case self::NOT_INITIALIZED:
        migrateToV0();
        // then:
    case 0:
        migrateToV1();
        // then:
    case 1:
        migrateToV2();
        // 
    case 2:
        migrateToV3();
        // 
    case 3:
        migrateToV4();
        //
}
```

## Or remove the switch.

Even if it is not very clean from a code coverage point of view (the functions may be defined implicitly and not resolved), I might also do it this way - especially if there's lots of them and I have to read them off a DB or a INI file, and/or the class they're defined in is not even loaded (this for *very* large classes/functions):

```
$transitions = [
    0 => 'migrateToV1',
    1 => [ 'Migrations', 'migrateToV2' ],
    2 => function() { die('Oh noes!'); },
    3 => 'migrateToV4',
];
foreach ($transitions as $ifVersion => $todo) {
    // if $todo is an array I can check the class exists
    if ($old_version === $ifVersion) {
        $newVersion = $todo($old_version);
        if (null === $newVersion) {
            $newVersion = $old_version +1;
        }
        $old_version = $newVersion;
    }
}
```